# jQuery Ui and dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I use jquery ui and want to have ui-tabs on ajax injected html.

If I use the code from documentation:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".tab" ).tabs();
});
```

on already existing HTML-Elements, it works.

But now, I want to open an jquery ui dialog with ajax content. Is there a possibility that the html inside is already converted to the jquery ui tab system?

Comment: hide the ajax container originally, and only show it after you have initialized the tabs and the ajax success is complete

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to load dynamic content before displaying the dialog box

```
<div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
    Default value
</div>

  $(function() {
    //Ajax call to load new text inside dialog-message
    $("#dialog-message").load("ajaxpage.php",function(){

        //Success callback, create and display the modal dialog

        //Delete dialog if already exists
        try{$(this).dialog('destroy');}catch(e){}

        //Create the new one
        $( this ).dialog({
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }  
          }
        });
    });
  });
```